# Android Java Screen On/Off events not working on Note 3

Tags: android, events, screen

So my problem is on Samsung Note 3 phone (Samsung s3 and Nokia are working ok). I  listen to screen on and off event with Broadcast receiver and when my app is running (even if it is running in background), everything is ok. I receive screen events just fine. But if I close app my screen events stop fireing on Note 3 phone (but they still work on S3 and Nokia).

In androidmanifest.xml I registered receiver like this:

```
    <receiver
         android:name=".lockScreenReceiver"
         android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in Broadcastreceiver java file / have this code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
    // Log event screen off.
  } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
    // Log event screen on.
  }
}
```

Anybody have any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set filters and register receiver in the activity, instead of doing this in manifest:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new lockScreenReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: But that wouldn't work when app is closed? Or am i missing something? My main priority is to track on and off screen when app is closed/killed (not just in background). Thanks for help :)

Comment: i think if you are not unregistering the receiver in  onDestroy , it still should listen to those events.

Comment: Not unregistrating crashes the app.